# Jenkins drop down list of build names of other job

Tags: groovy, build, jenkins

I would like to list out all successfull build names in the drop down menu that got built by  another job. I have seen the links to get all list of build ids in the drop down menu with parametrized and copy artifacts plugins. But I need to list with the actual build names set by Build Setter in the other job. Currently i am able to get list with #55,54,53,52.. etc., But I need to list with build names assigned to these builds that got set by build setter.

Code Snippet:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.AbstractProject
import hudson.model.Result
import hudson.util.RunList
AbstractProject<?, ?> otherJob = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName("iOS_plugin-5.0-build", AbstractProject.class)
RunList<?> builds = otherJob.getBuilds().overThresholdOnly(Result.SUCCESS)

def list = builds.limit(5).collect { it.number }
```

Regards,
Srinivas

Comment: `builds.limit(5).collect { it.description }` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for your reply Mahapatro. I tried with your solution, unfortunately it is not displaying any results. appreciate if any help on this.
My requirement is simple. I do CI builds with custom labels as build-ids and wants to list those names in the deploy job.

Comment: appreciate for any quick solution on this.

Answer (score 3):

I can retrieve the build name (set with the Build Name Setter plugin) with the "displayName" property of the build object.

Here is my working example, as a "Dynamic Choice Parameter" groovy plugin:

```
def jobname="build-my-project"
def list=[]
hudson.model.AbstractProject<?, ?> otherJob = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(jobname, hudson.model.AbstractProject.class)
hudson.util.RunList<?> builds = otherJob.getBuilds().overThresholdOnly(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
builds.limit(20).each{run -> list.add(run.displayName) }
list
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like Dynamic Choice parameter plugin is deprecated and not available. Any alternative to this?